# xslt traverser using parse-json()

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have below json here.

```
{
    "array1": [
        {
            "id": "banglore",
            "mappingData": [
                {
                    "name": "v1",
                    "Data": [
                        {
                            "idFromIndia": "0001"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "v2",
                    "Data": [
                        {
                            "idFromIndia": "0001"
                        },
                        {
                            "idFromIndia": "0001"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my xslt
1st I'm going inside array1 object and again traversing inside mappingData array and then if
name="v2" the traverse data inside Data array object

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="input-as-map" select="parse-json($input)" as="map(*)"/>
        <root>
            <data1>
              
                <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-map?array1?*?mappingData?*[string[@key='name']/string ='v2']?Data?*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="?idFromIndia"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                
            </data1>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here in the mappingData array when the name=v2 then traverse the data inside the `Data` array

Any suggestions would also be helpful

Comment: You've asked for suggestions but you haven't said what the problem is.

Comment: You're doing fine until you get to `string[@key='name']/string ='v2'`. At this point you suddenly start using operators that apply only to nodes in an (XML) tree, e.g. `string` selects elements named `string`, and `@key` selects attributes named `key`. This looks like a bad copy/paste of code written to operate on the XML representation of JSON, rather than the map/array representation of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you basically want the "XPath 3.1 lookup path" `?array1?*?mappingData?*[?name ='v2']?Data?*` instead of what you have tried, in your sample at some place it looks as if you in the middle of the lookup switched to using classic XPath path expressions/predicates that would work against the XML representation of the JSON, but for that you would need to use `json-to-xml` and obviously you would need to use a consistent approach.

The `for-each` is probably not needed:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$input-as-map?array1?*?mappingData?*[?name ='v2']?Data?*?idFromIndia"/>
```